# Custom cursors for canvas caricatures?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm making a whiteboard app just for fun and have tools like the brush tool, eraser, etc and I draw on an HTML5 canvas.

I'm trying to implement custom cursors for my tools (like brush, line, square) and was just going to use the CSS cursor property depending on which tool is selected but I'd like sizes to vary depending on the current line width.

For example, in MS Paint you'll notice with the brush and eraser tool, depending on the size of the line width, the cursor is differently sized when drawing on the canvas.

So I have two questions. The first is if I can use CSS still and somehow alternate the cursor size dynamically from JS.

The second is how you would implement this solution by just deleting the cursor and drawing your own on the canvas that follows the mouse movement. I'm a bit concerned that the latter would be quite glitchy and more complex so am hoping that the first one is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining the position of your own cursor does not work very well on the browsers. By the time you have handled the mouse move, waited for the next animation frame you are one frame behind. (drawing immediately to canvas in the mouse event does help) The is very off putting, even if you set the cursor to "none" so the two do not overlap, the 1/60th of a second can make a big difference from where you see your rendered cursor to and where the hardware cursor (for want of a better name) is.

But it turns out that the browsers Chrome and Firefox allow you to have full control of the hardware cursor image. I have personally exploited it to the limits and it is a robust and tolerant system.

I started with pre made cursors as DataURLs. But now most of my cursors are dynamic. If a control uses the mouse wheel, I add the wheel indicator on the cursor, when using resize cursor, instead of 8 directions N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW It is created on demand to line up with whatever I happen to be resizing at what ever angle it is. When drawing the cursor is continuously reorienting to avoid covering pixels I may be working on.

To set a custom cursor, set the elements style.cursor to an image URL, followed by two numbers that are the hotspot (Where the click is focused), and a cursor name. I just use the same name "pointer" and generate the image URL on the fly with toDataURL.

Below is a quick example of changing the cursor dynamically. I am unsure what the limits are in terms of size, but so far I haven't wanted a cursor that it has not given me. Some of them, in games have been very big (lol as cursors go) (128*128 pixels +)

Note a slight bug in code. Will return to fix the first rendered word being clipped soon.

The only issue with this is IE does not support this what of doing cursors, so you will need a fallback

```js
// create an image to use to create cursors
var image = document.createElement("canvas");
image.width = 200;
image.height = 14; 
image.ctx = image.getContext("2d"); 

// some graphic cursors 
var cursors = [
    "url('data:image/png;base64,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') 0 0, cursor",
"url('data:image/png;base64,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') 0 0, cursor ",
"url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAdCAYAAAC9pNwMAAAH/UlEQVRIS5VXC1CU1xX+lgVhFzAoICrljVATVGIUFcXUREYFB9PEIo7PCKahGQhoTDCi1nHSaiexjgk2iYqKVqCpjwTQIBEVBAFFEBGEACMPAxKQh67ALov97r+yLgrR3pkz+///fZx7Ht93zsrwYmMCl62mTKU4urtipIMDzNUaoKICqpZW3OP3OsoVyiHKjecdK3vOggDOr/OeBN+lIVBMnw44OQMvvQQYGQFaLdDdBfzyC1ByHci9DHx3HF0dHcjlvl2U00OdP5Ti4dzwL29vvPPpRmNTf//ZsBrhwE9KSiflFqXwmTPb24CbtPX4cSDua/So1eATwh9vGrB+MMU+XHEgIGCe14rl4+Ho9DsolcZ4+eUxGDbM2GBzM59zKEefuUADnZ6WAhxMAPILUMoFoZQCw4VPK56xdu3apKioKEcPDw8YGxvj0aNHePDgAfLzs2BvX4vx40c/paiK73sod1BUNAs9PZG8qCfkcjnq6+uRmpqKuLg4Ef8QCoOhG4aKx0ZHR2du377d09zcXH94Y2MjKqpvQ2lqAo26R7Jy5kz3Acq12hpeTIVXXoli/JkABkNNf589exbh4eEVDQ0Nb3CKGWGg2N3d/fusrKygMWPG6Lclpmbig05ntNk5w95IDY/yXMxtv4Rly7rh5CQSuV1ae/nyFEyeHAFTU1PpXcusS7t4BYdrZWjQyhFgroJFYyE+Wr/+B04vMlS8ctu2bfGxsbFyI5GuHNdLSvBapS18rZRwqMzC6qV+KNEocewf+/G+5y68+241QwH8+ivTrfNnuLk98cK+Exl4T+kHhboLa9zMYDNSgfTEFDw4+Km2tLR0DY9P6Hd1QXJy8tTg4GC9tQk/nMMqizcxP+MrWFZnYWFQEDqnBSAy5QY+alqBmJh6jBwJFBeHwNMzHgqFQtrbQSy5Jdeg19oOEfUn4WVvBxd/f0RfVeH6xyugKsoUWPcRiudR0pKTk+TBwUv0ipNTfkKI+Vx4Zieh799b0GdrD9eN+3HxZhU+bP0roqLyMHYskJ0dBR+fHXo319XVwSlbC8XDDph+PAdeXl6Y/v4G7JZNhGXS39GW8i3Rj0Ch+JDvDKyKiNiBRW9F6m/ORMDs9HvocvWCn7YJKo0aF1u1CK5Ox4ThRxASkgeRDjk5qzFx4h5YWlpKl9ZoNJi7Lxd542bij/WZkN27jY5xs3GmRYs/JG/AhYwzYtlhofhaVAReXbjIG87O/4WrqytkMl0ESkrLsDW7Caf6zGHbdR+rTRrhaaGmi8MwZw5gZcU1Jba8bA6YnPp910puYnGxHLW2Thimakd35z2sa7sCk+YcxO3dT3iiSGi4u/MzjIrewIgnxGDBggjY2trCxMREUt7X18fk6ZSw3NzcjB9/DOeaApDVqAjo7QUSE3fwWyhsbGz0oWpqasLlG9W436OFnZkWsj4NLmbOQ8Y5EvpVNAvFXXv3wCw8gje4Cxw5EgN//xCMHj1aIhChuLu7G+Xl5bhw4XMEBmYwbjq+7h/V1eDcXsyfH0QvWOnjLTAsLl1VVYW0tHVwdbyC9AxS6kl0C8WPvv4KWPMeaCXQ2joCR4++jvb2cTAzsyYme3H/fiFcXE5KVrq5AdbWT5T2PxF9OHEilHgOggNLl2CulpYWslkhz9iDKa81gNHCf8jeCWRZyeIvdsIs7M/A8MdW9PZ6E59LeNt8WnuKHM05lg1GQHoeagiP5eUBt2/rKpfwiosLJNgpiba7d4CdXxBCp3UW343ZgFHhf2GhdTY8chRfuAv5Q2saZIaRoYdoDcul4CIBb5HwleVAIxWvJH3U1etifG1hIF7dGgtMmca3QeqVOKSd7CgOsrAADKj8hS4lrM9nIRN1+09LpS1SVh9iOFad/A6YMQuwoTvFENmamUnAHQaOHXtyvrAgMBB4g3QvIMUiJl3ot8Yd1qYaFrFsKt+0RVop4Vhirm1bIF/Ap8msxkZyxmInsHHj4MeFhoYiiBR6/vx5EsZurF+vi+Vgo4cFrZDRIv8gditwKRd65hLrC37vgam7GXiptWHWCjp0pysWs+K48ldJ0KpYm6/TFXYxMdi8eTMEXGpqaqg4ErGxP8HXd6BqEe8bxSwiDFMRW6MP10nzeq4WLysp8ZEfQL74bVrMqjPrdZY7pRITGCBTikbAg7iuJeba6ed5SUkSyTx8+JBlchlhcwpZWUxQR51yofQWe4/WFkClAj5hDhFywtoB1Ums/Z4S9CVbtEmT2NAwrn4HgOVP+a+LeComSTucPg0ZMVbHLiMsLAxlZWWIjwfLpa4BvFXG7O7QwerAId15HM/UY/GRzkWmjTU8/7adMaPLv9kPLDkBvMWJAd0WPVHGC+xiuqeIID4e+75lwvgD9bU6hULYdWLvN9KCCsqzHcjjvTP4m0TgO276hE30FLpbEAKbtpXMysmcFFVXS7dfIjhTGePP6WoxfLh2UwwwYoTuJBU/H0skBessFT2XqLk8TTeG7DI557WMmHubjYrAbkUlW1eSgIJd7fBrQBWT7mpfL8b6ajGdSPCbqSMKEdubdPOBgyQIJhbHC3WZ/ReS+mrKO8St6XJeYBoPd3bSUabwrsA5DSef67YIgqn8GTiTDpw7L30SMfi/+up+5eKXVIFoigCKQtTfWXyyt6fVtE4ob2MTf4vRy3vSNTO1pH8S/6SkGR5m+Py8vzD9a/v/OzGSoN0g7aO/ByZYpP9OTClcpdDJknt/c/wP9EvvZb0C9IEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') 0 0, cursor "
];

// Do the stuff that does the stuff
var el = document.getElementById("customeCurs");
var over = false;


// set up canvas rendering
var c = image.ctx;

// some stuff to say and ABC are graphic flags
var stuff = "A C  Hello pointy clicky things are great and easy to use A B C B".split(" ");
var tHandle;
var wordPos=0;

function createCursor(){   // creates cursors from the canvas 
  // get a word from the word list
  var w = stuff[wordPos % stuff.length];
  if(w === "A" || w === "B" || w === "C"){ // display graphics cursor
                                           // just for fun. to much time on
                                           // my hands. I really need a job.
     var datURL;
     switch(w){
       case "A":
         datURL = cursors[0];
         break;
       case "B":
         datURL = cursors[1];
         break;
       case "C":
         datURL = cursors[2];
     }
     el.style.cursor = datURL;    

  }else{  // create a dynamic cursor from canvas image
  
    // get the size. Must do this 
    var size = c.measureText(w).width + 4;
    // resize the canvas
    image.width = size;
    image.height = 36;  
    c.font = "28px arial black";
    c.textAlign ="center";
    c.textBaseline = "middle";
    c.lineCap = "round";
    c.lineJoin = "round";
  
    // Please always give user a visual guide to the hotspot.
    // following draws a little arrow to the hotspot.
    // Always outline as single colours can get lost to the background
    c.lineWidth = 3;
    c.strokeStyle = "white";
    c.moveTo(1,5);
    c.lineTo(1,1);
    c.lineTo(5,1);
    c.moveTo(1,1);
    c.lineTo(8,8);
    c.stroke();

    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.lineWidth = 1;
    c.moveTo(1,5);
    c.lineTo(1,1);
    c.lineTo(5,1);
    c.moveTo(1,1);
    c.lineTo(8,8);
    c.stroke();

    c.lineWidth = 5;
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.fillStyle = "White";
  
    // Draw the text outline
    c.strokeText(w, image.width / 2, image.height / 2+2);
    // and inside
    c.fillText(w, image.width / 2, image.height / 2);

    // create a cursor and add it to the element CSS curso property
    el.style.cursor = "url('"+image.toDataURL("image/png")+"') 0 0 , pointer";  // last two
                                                       // numbers are the 
                                                       // cursor hot spot.
  }
  
  // Next word
  wordPos += 1;
  // if the mouse still over then do it again in 700 ticks of the tocker.
  if(over){
    tHandle = setTimeout(createCursor,700);
  }
    
}
  
// mouse over event to start cursor rendering
el.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
  over = true;
  if(tHandle === undefined){
    createCursor();
   }
});
el.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
  over = false; // clean up if the mouse moves out. But leave the cursor
  clearTimeout(tHandle);
  tHandle = undefined;
});
```

```html
<div id="customeCurs" >Move Mouse Over ME.</div>
<!-- Some say don't put style in HTML doc! The standards are indifferent. The author is lazy :P -->
<span style="font-size:small;color:#BBB;">Sorry IE again you miss out.</span>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks